# Order an ordered sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query to get the 8 ships with most orders, the thing is after this query I would like to have them ordered by their ID

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders 
FROM Shippers
LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName
ORDER BY NumberofOrders DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT ShipperName, NumberOfOrders
FROM (SELECT s.ShipperName, s.ShipperId, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders 
      FROM Shippers s LEFT JOIN
           Orders o
           ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
      GROUP BY ShipperName, s.ShipperId
      ORDER BY NumberofOrders DESC
      LIMIT 8
     ) s
ORDER BY ShipperId;
```